# Django Static/Media Files in the same Server

Tags: django, postgresql, digital-ocean

I just deployed my django project in the cloud server digital ocean with $20/mo ,with  ram and disk are more than adequate. My application atmost gets 200 users registered per month, consequently they will be having some set of tasks which produces data over 10 models. FYI,This application has a File upload task where user has to upload files 3-4 times. So my doubt is do I need to take another server for serving static files.With the above provided info, can you suggest anything.

Comment: No, you don't need a separate server. What's your question?

Comment: The question is about when to go for separate server for static files., As I told that my project has maximum of 200 users registered per month, does that make django server slow to serve static files.